# How to copy a non necessarily contiguous portion of a row to another sheet if a value from a given column is greater than 0?

Tags: excel, vba

I struggle a lot with VBA, as I'm very rookie to it...

I have to convert a stock of products to another format, where there are multiple pairs of size and quantity, that need to be converted to a unique pair of size and quantity for each product size, if there is a stock greater than 0. But I can't manage how to do it in VBA.

The best I could do is something like that, that copy the row if the value > 0 :

```
Public Sub Copytest()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lr)

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
        If ws2.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
            ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of the source and target sheets :

[image: schema]

Comment: allright, done. Actually I had an attempt but it was so far from what I was trying to achieve that I was ashamed to post it haha

Comment: Actually, this is doable just with the power query https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqQ3Ftt9q1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a basic book on programming.  You have to program the detail steps that you would do by hand.  Here is, IMHO, a good start with good practices:  meaningful names, indentation, comments:

```
Public Sub Copytest()
  Dim irow1&, icol1&, irow2&, lastrow&
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim prodid, otherattr, size, quan ' cell values
  Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
  lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  irow2 = 1 ' the output row
  For irow1 = 2 To lastrow ' the input row
    prodid = ws1.Cells(irow1, 1) ' productid
    otherattr = ws1.Cells(irow1, 8) ' other attrib
    For icol1 = 2 To 6 Step 2 ' the input column
      size = ws1.Cells(irow1, icol1)
      quan = ws1.Cells(irow1, icol1 + 1)
      If quan > 0 Then
        ws2.Cells(irow2, 1) = prodid
        ws2.Cells(irow2, 2) = size
        ws2.Cells(irow2, 3) = quan
        ws2.Cells(irow2, 4) = otherattr
        irow2 = irow2 + 1
      End If
    Next icol1
  Next irow1
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```